# Blank memory slot information in CPU-Z?

Tags: memory, cpu-z

My ASUS laptop came with one 4GB memory stick and I recently added another 4GB to speed things up. There's no problem and everything works fine.

Now, I installed CPU-Z to check about my memory, but the readings are a little strange:

Here's what it shows in **Memory** tab:

[image]

But, in SPD, **only the information about the first slot** is displayed:

[image]

The second (and also the #3 and #4) looks like this:

[image]

Why isn't there any info about the other stick? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: is cpuz running as admin?

Comment: @FrankThomas, that's it! It now shows the other stick at slot #3. (And strangely, the size of the memory is showing at exact 8 Gigabytes instead of 7982 MB). You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. But can you tell me why it couldn't get the info in normal mode?

Comment: How do you run it as admin though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click on the CPU-Z icon and select 'Run As Administrator'. 
[[Click here for an image of the right-click menu.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUHSi.png)

Then go to the Memory and SPD tabs and you will get your memory details.

Comment: As of version 1.97.0 (x32 and x64) this method does not work.  I have information under memory tab but not SPD tab on my server.  Logged in as Administrator and ran as Administrator.  This is the portable version just downloaded today.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to why CPUZ displays proper in Admin mode is that running programs in admin mode tells the OS to allow that program to have access to otherwise restricted data w/the exception of admin privileges. This is very common mistake that gamers run into and have problems when playing game programs. As a matter of fact a common report of the program CPUZ was disappearing upon free upgrade from Win 7, 8 to Win 10. I had to re-download and re-install it myself when I upgraded to Win 10. Why windows does this is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the SETUP version? Same thing happened to me after I updated the program to the latest version (1.80.0 as today). I fixed mine by uninstalling and reinstalling it. Not sure if one can encounter this bug if using the portable (ZIP) version.

Comment: After more tests it seems like a bug in CPU-Z. When it doesn't show the first time from a fresh system start, a reboot will make it appear, regardless of having OC or no. Another reason to believe it is a bug is after running other system monitor programs such as HWiNFO or benchmark programs like 3DMark that scan system hardware, once blanked SPD info will appear without needing a reboot, just need to reopen CPU-Z.